# Why is the number of samples smaller than the number of values in my decision tree?

Tags: random-forest, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I'm using scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier for a classification problem. When taking a closer look at one of the trees I noticed that the number of samples at the root was 662, but there were 507 instances of the first class and 545 of the second. What's going on or did I understand something wrong? Is the number of samples actually the number of unique samples and since I used bootstrap aggregation there are many samples that were chosen multiple times?
[image: Picture of the decision tree]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems to display unique samples, the others have been duplicated by the bootstrap sampling.

There's the 0.632 rule - when you have N items and you take a random sample of size N with replacement (as bootstrap does), you only get 63.2% of the samples from N, the rest are duplicates.

That roughly matches what you've seen: 0.632 * (507+545) = 665 unique samples.

You can also try it with some Python code:

```
samples = np.arange(507 + 545)

bootstrap_sample = np.random.choice(samples, size=len(samples), replace=True)

print(len(np.unique(bootstrap_sample)))
```

This always prints values closely around 665.